CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Origin checking failed
Here is my setup:
localhost (Windows 11)
  - Nginx
      listening on port 80 and 443, 80 is NOT automatically redirected to 443
      each proxy_passed to http://wsgi-server where wsgi-server=127.0.0.1:8080
  - waitress_wsgi running as a service on port 8080

Here is Django config:
<!-- email_test.html -->
<!-- ... -->
<form action="{% url 'identity:email_test' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ email_form }}
  {% translate 'Send email' as submit_translated %}
  <!-- I use django_bootstrap5 -->
  {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content=submit_translated extra_classes='w-100'%}
</form>

# settings.py ----------
MIDDLEWARE = {
  # ...
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  # ...
}

# forms.py -------------
class EmailTestForm(forms.Form):
  email = forms.EmailField(
    # help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    label=_('Email'),
    max_length=128,
  )

# views.py -------------
def email_test(request):
  context = {}
  context.update(template_globals())
  if request.method == "POST":
    email_form = EmailTestForm(request.POST)
    if email_form.is_valid():
      email_obj = EmailMessage(subject='Hello', body='Email body',
                               from_email='noreply@nutrihub.hnet',
                               to=[email_form.cleaned_data.get('email')])
      email_obj.send(fail_silently=False)
  else:
    email_form = EmailTestForm()

  context['email_form'] = email_form
  return render(request, "identity/email_test.html", context)

Here are my test resuts when I visit the URL on browser:

py manage.py runserver (default port 8000), browser http://127.0.0.1:8000, empty settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: Works fine.
Browser http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 or https://localhost or https://127.0.0.1 with individual entry not in settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: CSRF error.
Browser http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 or https://localhost or https://127.0.0.1 with individual entry not settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: Works fine.
Browser https://mymachine.net with this entry in etc/hosts resolving to 127.0.0.1 and not in settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: CSRF error.
Browser https://mymachine.net with this entry in etc/hosts resolving to 127.0.0.1 and in settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: Works fine.
Browser http://localhost:8080 or http://localhost or http://mymachine.net:8080: Works fine.

Does this mean that for (2-5), since the actual server the Django app runs on is the WSGI server on port 8080, request forwarded from the web server is not considered same site?

I was able to solve this. With this solution, I did not have to add any entries in settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS.

Nginx config:

  upstream wsgi-server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
  server {
    # ...
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://wsgi-server/;
      # These resolved CSRF error
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
  }


Waitress WSGI config (to let X-Forwarded-* pass through to Django):

# waitress_wsgi.py
  serve(application,
        trusted_proxy='proxy-ip',
        trusted_proxy_headers=('x-forwarded-host', 'x-forwarded-proto',
                               'x-forwarded-port'))

With this, http|https, localhost|127.0.0.1|mymachine.net, anyport, started working with no errors.
